# Hibernate upsert where id=value

Tags: hibernate

I am trying to do the following:

```
sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createCriteria(SeekerRefreshModel.class)
            .add(Restrictions.eq("SJT_USER_ID", seekerrefreshmodel.getSeekerRefreshPK().getSjtUserId()))
            .add(Restrictions.eq("COOKIE_VALUE", seekerrefreshmodel.getSeekerRefreshPK().getCookieValue()))
            .saveOrUpdate(seekerrefreshmodel);
```

However `saveOrUpdate` is not liking that and telling me:

```
The method saveOrUpdate(SeekerRefreshModel) is undefined for the type Criteria
```

How can I add a where to my upsert.

Cheers

Answer (score -1):

just do

```
sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().saveOrUpdate(seekerrefreshmodel);
```

with the Criteria object you are constructing you can search/load this object.

Comment: I cannot do this as the primary key is a compound of three different attributes, SJT_USER_ID, COOKIE_VALUE and TIMESTAMP